# Use poll() to check for file modification

Tags: c, linux

There is a file and I would like to check it with `poll()` that the contents have changed.

On Raspi there is a file called gpio value, if the value changed the `poll()` was triggered with POLLPRI, I would like to do the same with an ordinary file.

Here is the code I am using to check the GPIO file:

```
int gpio_fd = gpio_fd_open();
int timeout = POLL_TIMEOUT;
struct pollfd fdset;
int nfds = 1;
char *buf[MAX_BUF];
int len;
int rc;
fdset.fd = gpio_fd;
fdset.events =  POLLPRI | POLLERR | POLLHUP | POLLNVAL; // POLLIN | | POLLOUT 
unsigned int c1, c2, c3;
do{
    rc = poll(&fdset, 1, timeout);
```

And the gpio_fd_open function:

```
int gpio_fd_open() {
    printf("opening File: " SYSFS_GPIO_DIR "\n");

    int fd, len;
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    len = snprintf(buf, sizeof (buf), SYSFS_GPIO_DIR);
    fd = open(buf, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("gpio/fd_open");
    }
    return fd;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to use `poll()` on sysfs, and on _gpio_ in particular. GPIO doesn't allow to track if value changed, AFAIK electric signalling doesn't allow that. How do you expect that from kernel?

Comment: this code is working for me good for GPIO , but i would like to change it for custome file, if some data arrive into it make poll trigger. if im was not clear :)

Comment: @myaut: actually, you **can** use `poll()` if interrupt is enabled for this particular GPIO pin. It's even recommended in [Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt)

Comment: @TextTexer: please specify which exactly files you want to use `poll()` for.

Comment: Dear TexTexer the file what was said is should be /tmp/filename contains only 1 char "1". This is the file , and if the value change make interrupt for the poll()  (POLLPRI example)

Comment: myaut i know that i can use it and i also using it too. but i would like to use the poll for non gpio file

Comment: @TextTexer: I doubt that `poll()` can do this for you. If you want to watch for file modifications (i.e. getting event when file was modified), you should use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) API. Here is an [example](http://www.stev.org/post/2012/09/22/Linux-Programming-Using-inotify-for-detecting-file-modifications.aspx) how to do so.

Comment: @Sam Protsenko I need to watch the file and the Value changes(GPIO) with the same function, this is the poll(). For now the kernel making POLLPRI event when a file was modified( changes happens on the GPIO "leg") , but if i add a normal tmp file for the list, or just alone, to the poll(), it always will return immediately.
Right now i would like to make some kind of system call to creat pollpri event if i change my tmp file , or some reading where i can start to dug how should i do this . Regards :)

Comment: Now it's clear what you are trying to achieve. You should add this information to your original question (your 3 last comments). Also, in my opinion, modifying `poll()` system call in kernel would be too hard. Much more easier solution is to create some wrapper function (in your program) which would probe file: if it's regular file -- this function will use `inotify`, if it's gpio file -- use `poll`.

Comment: You can `poll()` the inotify file descriptor, so it's just the matter of returning an appropriate fd.

Answer (score 10):

In Linux, unlike with your special GPIO file, you can not poll the fd to an open ordinary file like that.

To watch a file for changes you can use the `inotify` family of functions.  Conveniently for you they use a file descriptor which can be passed to `poll()` along with your GPIO file descriptor, so you can watch both at the same time.

So, some minor additions/changes to your code:

```
int fw_fd = file_watch_fd("/some/file/to/watch");
struct pollfd fdset[2];
int nfds = 2;
int rc;
fdset[0].fd = gpio_fd;
fdset[0].events =  POLLPRI | POLLERR | POLLHUP | POLLNVAL;
fdset[1].fd = fw_fd;
fdset[1].events = POLLIN;
do {
    rc = poll(fdset, nfds, timeout);
```

You are polling on the inotify fd, which you read to return one more watched events which occurred.  Since this code is only watching one file for one event, we're pretty sure what the event is, but we still need to read it out of the fd, then we can actually read the file.

```
    if (fdset[1].revents & POLLIN) {
        if (ready(fw_fd)) {
            /* file has changed, read it */
        }
    }
```

Here is the **file_watch_fd()** function:

```
int file_watch_fd ( const char * filename ) {
        static int      inot    = ERR;
        static int      iflags  = IN_CLOEXEC | IN_NONBLOCK;
        static uint32_t mask    = IN_MODIFY;
        int             watch;

        if (inot == ERR) {
                inot = inotify_init1(iflags);
                if (inot == ERR) return ERR;
        }
        watch = inotify_add_watch(inot, filename, mask);
        if (watch == ERR) return ERR;
        return inot;
}
```

And here is the **ready()** function:

```
int ready ( int inot ) {
        uint64_t                buffer[8192];
        ssize_t                 nr;
        char *                  p;
        size_t                  n;
        struct inotify_event *  evP;
        int                     ready   = 0;

        while ((nr = read(inot, (char *)buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
                for (p = buffer; p < buffer + nr; p += n) {
                        evP = (struct inotify_event *)p;
                        if (evP->mask & IN_MODIFY) ready = 1;
                        n = sizeof(struct inotify_event) + evP->len;
                }
        }
        return ready;
}
```

*(People experience in the use of inotify will notice that I ran roughshod over the functionality of it to keep this example as simple as I can)*

Comment: No, you actually `poll()` on the main inotify fd, the "watch" fd's get returned in the `inotify_event`s returned when you read the inotify fd.  Then you can match up the fd in the event with which file changed.  In this particular case, there is only a single file, so no point in that really.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what your example shows? Your "file_watch_fd" function does return the main inotify fd. Also you seem to be arguing with yourself, which is confusing...

Comment: The comment to which I was replying has been deleted.

Comment: Ah, that explains it.

Comment: I'm trying your code, and it seems to get stuck inside the ready() function, after checking 8 events (the first one is the actual IN_MODIFY event, the other 7 are empty.) I'll report back here if I figure out what my issue is.

Comment: It was my fault, I had forgotten to include the iflags when initializing the inotify object. Wish I could upvote your answer more than once

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful

Comment: You can use POLL on sysfs GPIO value file. It is stated in kernel docs: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt